# kafka-connect-elasticsearch: How to sync elasticsearch with consumer group?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to query messages in a Kafka topic but not all messages, not from the beginning. I just need to see which messages are not yet committed based on a consumer group. So, basically what I want to have is to delete the documents whose offset is lower than a consumer group offset.

At this point, if I use elastic-connector, is there any way or a workaround to delete documents from the elastic index after a message is consumed and committed?

Or, should I use Kafka Streams and how?

Answer (score 0):

The sink connector only deletes documents when that property is explicitly enabled and there is a null valued record for a document ID in the topic you're reading. This means you need to actually consume this null record and have it be processed by the connector

> see which messages are not yet committed

This would imply messages that have **not** been processed by the connector, making them not searchable in Elasticsearch

> delete the documents whose offset is lower than a consumer group offset

If you created a fresh index in Elasticsearch that's only used by the connector, you could pause the connector, then [truncate the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929695/truncate-index-in-elasticsearch), then resume the connector

> is there any way or a workaround to delete documents from the elastic index after a message is consumed and committed

Directly use the DELETE API

Comment: hi @OneCricketeer , thanks for your precious answer but i guess i'm misunderstood. what i meant that i just want to query events that are not yet consumed by another specific consumer group. i didn't mean stream api.
what do you think about this scenario? 
1- write events to an elasticsearch index via kafka connector in the format like this (doc_id = key, doc = {partition, offset, event})
2- get partition and offset info last consumed event when consuming.
3- delete elastic documents where partition equals and offset is lower than the last consumed event.

Comment: You only make the connector sink data from a specific set of topics. That set of topics (the sink connector itself, rather) has its own consumer group. You can't make the connector process data from other consumer groups. And like I said, the connector only deletes documents on a specific tombstone event, not on any other data